# Error while downloading .deb packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I formatted my disk and installed Ubuntu again. Now, I'm trying to install Steam and Chrome with `sudo apt install`. But, I'm getting following error:

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'steam_latest.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'steam_latest.deb'
```

or

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
```

But, I tried to install by typing `sudo dpkg -i packagename` and I succeed to install. Why I'm getting this error? Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the multiverse repository enabled?

Comment: Your details are ambiguous and incomplete. Please tell us the whole/actual commands that you are attempting. You should also include the entire output of these commands, not just the parts you think are important. Please edit your question to complete this information. Also add `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. You should also tell us exactly what other actions you are taking install this software. It's clear you're doing something wrong but we can't tell you what that is if you don't first tell us what you're doing. Tag me @nmath when you're finished or I'll miss it.

Comment: FYI: downloading and installing `.deb` packages is generally not a good way to install software, especially if you don't know what you're doing. If you install incompatible software this way, you can break your system.